# Beamer: center a reduced-width block

Tags: beamer

I am trying to reduce the width and center a `block` in my Beamer presentation so that it aligns with a following `beamercolorbox`. I have read in various posts that, in order to reduce the width and center a block, I should put it in `minipage` and `center` environments. But, oddly, doing that does not center the reduced-width `block` exactly, so that it does not align with the following `beamercolorbox`.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usecolortheme{beetle}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=gray!50}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=black!60}
\setbeamercolor{box}{fg=black,bg=gray!50}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
\begin{block}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{block}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\vspace{-10pt}

\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=4pt]{box}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{beamercolorbox}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image]

What is going on here? Why is the `block` not centered exactly? (I measured it, it is the `block` that is not centered, not the `beamercolorbox`.)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If I compile your MWE with a current installation of TeX, it renders fine and both boxes are centered. Which version and installation of TeX do you use?

Comment: Running `pdflatex --version` returns `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)`. So do I need to update TeX?

Comment: I don't fully know, but it may be a reason for this.

Comment: Indeed, upgrading to TeX Live 2021 resolved the issue. Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it could be solved by updating the TeX installation as pointed out in the comments.